# Adding additional logic to my Formula

Tags: formula, formula-field

Aim : 
On the contact record any time the "OtherCountry or "MailingCountry" is populated with the value UK then the field "UK Email Consent" needs to be populated. My validation rule should also provide an error if the Uk_Email_Consent__c is set and neither of the Countries are set to 'UK'

This is my current formula, which works fine for "other country" but I am having issues adding the "Mailingcountry" to my logic.

```
AND(
   /* Run Validation Rules custom setting must be True */
        $Setup.ValidationOverrides__c.validation_rules__c,

OR(
 AND((OtherCountry<>'UK'), NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Uk_Email_Consent__c)))), 
 AND((OtherCountry= 'UK'), ISBLANK(TEXT(Uk_Email_Consent__c)))

))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a stab at it

```
AND(
   /* Run Validation Rules custom setting must be True */
        $Setup.ValidationOverrides__c.validation_rules__c,

OR(
 AND( (MailingCountry <> 'UK'),(OtherCountry<>'UK'), NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Uk_Email_Consent__c)))), 
 AND( OR ((MailingCountry = 'UK'), (OtherCountry= 'UK')), ISBLANK(TEXT(Uk_Email_Consent__c)))

))
```

This also throws a validation error if the `Uk_Email_Consent__c` is set and neither of the Countries are set to 'UK' which was not in your requirement but seems to be what you wanted the rule to do.

Comment: thanks for providing that formula. yes you are correct i will update my main question to include the additional logic. The problem i am encountering now is that regardless of the value being entered into the mailing or other country Uk_Email_Consent__c is becoming required

Comment: @Masond3 - I just tested it in my Org without your Outer And (Setup value) and it worked as expected. If either is UK then Picklist required. If both are not UK and Picklist is populated throw error, if either is UK and pick list is populated OK

Comment: You are correct. apologies for looking at this again

Comment: @Masond3 - No worries. End result is whats important!

Comment: ha that is true. really appreciate your swift response. have a great day pal